# InstallShield 2010 causes exception in Wintrust.dll while code signing on Windows 8

Tags: exception, windows-8, installshield-2010

I recently upgraded my dev computer from Windows 7 to Windows 8 (new box). Since the upgrade, InstallShield 2010 causes an exception towards the end of the build cycle, which seems to be caused by an unhandled exception in Wintrust.dll at the point of code signing.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a latent bug in InstallShield 2010, as that version of the IDE does not support Windows 8. This problem was fixed in later versions of InstallShield, although I forget exactly which version (likely InstallShield 2012 or so).

Comment: Thanks. Are you aware of a work around? InstallShield is a pricy product and also don't want to upgrade yet (will create too many other complications).

Comment: Only workarounds I know are: don't build on Windows 8, or don't sign (I think the problem occurs while reading artifacts of the signed file). In theory you might be able to stub out a replacement wrapper for wintrust and dll-jack InstallShield, but that's a lot of effort and craziness.

Comment: Ok thanks. My current work around is to build in a Windows 7 VM on the Windows 8 box. It took a while to configure - but will tide me over for now. Thanks for your info.